# append element for the third div only and after that every fifth div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a article which contains a bunch of `paragraphs`. After the third `paragraph` I need to add a Advertisement slot. Then after that every five paragraph add another Advertisement slot. I try to mimic what I want to accomplish using these `HTML tags`.

```js
for(var i = 0; i<tasks.length; i++){
  if(tasks[i].tagName == 'DIV'){
    if (i && (i % 5 == 0)) { 
         //Logic to add elements go here
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3(Here is where the element will be added)</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8(Here is where the element will be added)</div>
```

Comment: `(i % 5 == 2)` will return true if i==2, 7, 12, 17...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `nth-child()` selector and set `5n + 3` which is every 5 elements from 3  [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/2138/)

```
document.querySelectorAll('div:nth-child(5n + 3)')
```

Comment: I like your style

Comment: nice, very clean

Answer (score 3):

Get all the div elements and then iterate through them, start your for loop from 2nd index and then increment in the steps of 5

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i = 2; i<div.length; i += 5){
  let para = document.createElement("P");
  let t = document.createTextNode("new content");
  para.appendChild(t);
  //div[i].after(para); this is experimental feature, might not be supported in all the browsers
  div[i].parentNode.insertBefore(para, div[i].nextSibling);
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3(Here is where the element will be added)</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8(Here is where the element will be added)</div>
```

Comment: this make sense, but needs the elements need to be added in between 3 and 4

Comment: You can use `insertBefore` to add the new element after 3rd div. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply let i be zero based, then add an offset:

```
var tasks = document.body.children;
var off = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length - off; i++){
  if(tasks[i+off].tagName == 'DIV'){
    if ( !(i % 5)) {
      tasks[i+off].innerHTML += "sth";
    }
  }
```